# Unexpected output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{

    const int i=10;
    int *p =(int *) &i;
    *p = 5;
    cout<<&i<<" "<<p<<"\n";
    cout<<i<<" "<<*p;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

0x22ff44 0x22ff44

10 5

Please Explain.

Comment: `c` tag removed. Your program does not compile with a C compiler: `<iostream>` is not recognized, the usage of `<<` is all wrong. Besides `const` means different things to C or C++: they are different languages

Comment: Isn't it nice when constants are not constants that is what you get :)

Comment: @pmg His program is clearly not C, but the meaning of const is the same in both languages (at least when applied to the common subset, as is the case here).

Comment: In C the cast is wrong. Without the cast a compiler must issue a diagnostic message (at least) when it finds the assignment between incompatible types. If this program was [converted to C](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dnrynf.html) the explanation for unexpected output is ignoring compiler diagnostics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've attempted to modify a const object, so the behavior is
undefined.  The compiler has the right to suppose that the const
object's value doesn't change, which probably explains the
symptoms you see.  The compiler also has the right to put the
const object in read only memory.  It generally won't do so for
a variable with auto lifetime, but a lot will if the const has
static lifetime; in that case, the program will crash (on most
systems).

Answer (score 12):

Well, your code obviously contains undefined behaviour, so anything can happen.

In this case, I believe what happens is this:

In C++, const ints are considered to be compile-time constants. In your example, the compiler basically replaces your "i" with number 10.

Comment: Close ... it replaces occurrences of `i` with the literal value `10` and causes [nasal demons to fly out of your nose](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/msg/dfe1ef367547684b?pli=1) when it encounters `*p = 5`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a shot at it: since there's no logical reason for that output, the compiler must have optimised that wretched `cout<<i<<" "` to a simple `"cout<<"10 "`. But it's just a hunch.

Comment: It's more than a hunch. The very first line of the function says that i is constant, so it must of course always have the value 10. (The next line then makes the program inalid.)